# Command pattern - undo function in textbox issue

Tags: c#, wpf, command-pattern

I have several TextBoxes which share the same `TextChanged` listener.

```
private void text1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CommandManager.InvokeExecute(new SaveUpdateCommand((TextBox)sender));
}
```

When an event occures, the old `TextBox` object is being put onto a stack here:

```
internal static class CommandManager
{
    private static Stack<Command> commandStack = new Stack<Command>();

    internal static void InvokeExecute(Command cmd)
    {
        cmd.Execute();
        commandStack.Push(cmd);
    }

    internal static void InvokeUndo()
    {
        if (commandStack.Count > 0) commandStack.Pop().Undo();
    }
}
```

However for the undo to work i need to click the InvokeUndo button twice and i can not figure out why. Besides the necessary doubleclick all works well. Here is the Command implementation.

```
internal class SaveUpdateCommand : Command
{
    private TextBox textBox;
    private string oldText;

    public SaveUpdateCommand(TextBox textBox)
    {
        this.textBox = textBox;
        this.oldText = textBox.Text;
    }

    internal override void Execute()
    {
        //Not implemented within this command.
    }

    internal override void Undo()
    {
        textBox.Text = oldText;
    }
}
```

Thank you for any insight. The GUI was done with VS2015 designer with WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written such a `undo/do-again` class quite long ago && recognized **exactly the same error** as you do.

IMHO this depends on the following:

- you  change the text of the textbox
- the textbox fires the `exe` command:    `<------------------------------+`

  - your list gets a new item with the command item                                  `|`
  - the command item contains the actual text                                           `|`
- now you click the `undo` button:                                                                    `|`

  - you recieve the old text of the textbox                                                   `|`
  - you assign the old text to the textbox                                                    `|`
  - assigning the old text to the textbox the text obviously changes          `|`
  - the textbox sends a new exe command     `------------------------+`
  - now you have the same item in the list again which you ar looking at the moment

This is why you have to double click your `undo` button befroe you think the text changes...

Actually the text **changed**, but as it stays the same you **don't** recognize it by any **UI Update**.

You see the nice ASCII arrow?? `^^`

Comment: Ascii arrow saves the day.

Comment: @Marvelcz i think so too :) if it helped you pls upvote... THX